# Lastpass and key bindings

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, lastpass

I'm using lastpass in Firefox (on Ubuntu 13.04 with the latest stable rev of Cinnamon). Each time that I begin to fill in a text field and attempt to press the down arrow to select a list Firefox provides of cached values, Lastpass intercepts the down arrow key asking me to log in.

Can I override this behaviour by disabling this quick key in lastpass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to disable the 'Click Icons in Field'. While that will resolve the issue, it will also force your to go through the LastPass icon in your browser's toolbar to select a different login if the one that has been auto-filled isn't the one you want to use.

To disable 'Click Icons in Field':

- Click 'Preferences' from the LastPass menu in your browser's toolbar
- Go to 'Notifications'
- Un-check 'Click Icons in Field'

Source of the solution: https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=104305#p357065

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)).